# Configuring Web Flow for use with JSF

Tags: jsf, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I am trying to do Configuring Web Flow for use with JSF. from the following site

http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/ch13s04.html

but I am getting the following error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The prefix "si" for attribute "si:schemaLocation" associated with an element type "beans" is not bound. flowwithjsf.xml /WebFlowWithJSFIntegration/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring   line 12 XML Problem
```

Here is my XML it looks just like the site:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:webflow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
    xmlns:faces="http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces"
    si:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/faces/spring-faces-2.2.xsd">

    <!-- Executes flows: the central entry point into the Spring Web Flow system -->
    <webflow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor">
        <webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
            <webflow:listener ref="facesContextListener"/>
        </webflow:flow-execution-listeners>
    </webflow:flow-executor>

    <!-- The registry of executable flow definitions -->
    <webflow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" base-path="/WEB-INF">
        <webflow:flow-location-pattern value="**/*-flow.xml" />
    </webflow:flow-registry>

    <!-- Configures the Spring Web Flow JSF integration -->
    <faces:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" />

    <!-- A listener maintain one FacesContext instance per Web Flow request. -->
    <bean id="facesContextListener" 
        class="org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowFacesContextLifecycleListener" />  

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing `si:schemaLocation="...` by `xsi:schemaLocation="...` 
I think that is why you are having this error

Comment: it did not help.. I made the changes but I am now getting this error.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050584/trying-to-add-jsf-to-my-spring-webflow-project-and-now-my-webflow-will-not-worki

Answer (score 0):

"To use this schema, include it in one of your infrastructure-layer beans files"
10.2 [Spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/2.4.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/pdf/webflow-reference.pdf)